# Ionic - ng-src load icons based on conditions

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my ionic app, I need to load icons using ng-src. Depending on the format of the document, corresponding icon needs to be displayed.

I was trying to do something like

```
<img ng-src="{{format === 'docx' ? '../img/Word-icon.png' : '../img/PDF-icon.png')}}">
```

If the format is docx (I have verified that format value is coming correctly), then display Word-icon.png. For everything else display PDF-icon.png.

This is not working. In fact the page stops loading when I do this. It does not throw an error in the browser console but also does not load the page. Icons are stored in the img directory inside the www folder in the ionic app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had unnecessary `)` at the end of expression.

```
<img ng-src="{{format === 'docx' ? '../img/Word-icon.png' : '../img/PDF-icon.png'}}">
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the extra brace. Now the page has started loading, however, the image still does not load. Image shows as blank in the Ionic app.

Comment: Do you have `ng-app="myApp"`(myApp would be your app module) directive on page to run angular on page?

Comment: Yes, there are several other angular statements on the page which work fine.

Comment: @kayasa are you sure it's not just a path issue? What do you see in the developer tools when you look at the element where the image is suppose to be?

Comment: can you check `src` attribute on that element? Then you might messed up with image path issue